# NoReverseMatch at/myapp/products/

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
NoReverseMatch at/myapp/products/
Reverse for 'product_detail' not found. 'product_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. 

Error during template rendering 
In template C:\Users\User\job\mysite\myvenv\myproject\myapp\templates\base_generic.html, error at line 8

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit="no">
```

I am new to Django and using version 2.1
When I browse at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
I have the error above on clicking Products instead of getting the product name.

At `base_generic.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit="no">

<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:products'%}">Products</a></li>

At product_list.html,

{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% if product_list %}

{% for product in product_list %}

<a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">{{product.name}}</a>

{% endfor %}

{% else %}

No product 

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

At myapp urls.py,

```
from django. urls import path 
from myapp import views

app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
      path('products/', views. ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'), 
      path('product/<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'), 
]
```

At `models.py`,

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse 

class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter a brief description of the product.")

        def __str__(self):
               return self.name

        def get_absolute_url(self):
               return reverse('myapp/product_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

At views.py,

```
class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
       model = Product 

       def product_list_view(request):
              products = Product.objects.filter(name=name)
              return render(
                     request,
                     'myapp/product_list.html', 
                      {'products':product}
              )

class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Product 

         def product_detail(request, pk):
                product_id = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
                 return render(
                        request, 
                        'microfinance/product_detail.html',
                        context={'product_id':product}
                 )
```

What should I do to get the product name on clicking Products and from there (also on clicking the product name) get the product detail?

Comment: Someone should help me, please.

Comment: Someone, please help me to the solution of the above question

Comment: I need help, please.

Comment: Thank you, benvc. But the post has format itself.

Comment: You have an extra `"` in your `<meta>` tag.

Comment: I have removed the extra ". Still getting the error.

Comment: I need help, please.

Comment: Random guess: here `path('product/<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail')` the name is `product-detail`, but you're using `product_detail` (with an underscore) in `reverse('myapp/product_detail', args=[str(self.id)])`. Also, in the HTML file here `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit="no"` there's an unmatched double quote (the last one). You may try removing the quotes around `no` or escaping them.

Comment: I appreciated your suggestions but it didn't work, ForceBru.

Comment: Help me to check it again. I just added myapp views.py, ForceBru.

Comment: looks like that should be `myapp:product_detail` instead of `myapp/product_detail` in the `reverse` function

Comment: Thanks very much for your concern. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In the `reverse` function you need to pass `app_name:name` and not `app_name/name`.

In your case:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('myapp:product_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#id5) for full explanation.

Comment: Thanks to dan-klasson's, ForceBru and benvc. You guys are wonderful.

Comment: @Cletus Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you appreciate the help, then upvote and make sure to mark answers as accepted if they solved your problem.

Comment: Okay but I noticed something now. When I repeat same code on FAQ, it shows no error but its not working  or displaying. What could be the cause here, please?...

Comment: Any ideas, please.

Comment: @Cletus I don't know what that means. Ask/create another question

Comment: Thank you, dan-klasson.

Comment: How do I upvote and ensure to mark answers as accepted, since it's showing me that I can't vote my own post?...

Comment: @Cletus You can upvote other people's questions and answers. You can also accept answers after a certain time limit has transpired. Which should be around now.